# Jquery to change value of "value" attribute in xml element

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Example (snippet) :

```
 <FIELD name="xxxxxxxx" refname="xxxx" type="String" reportable="dimension">
  <WHEN field="xxxxxxxx" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="n.a." />
      <LISTITEM value="Test" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </WHEN>
  <WHEN field="yyyyyyyyyyyyy" value="yyyyyyy">
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="n.a." />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </WHEN>
</FIELD>
```

When I do:

```
 var $listItem = $(xmlDoc).find("FIELD[name='" + dependentFieldType + "'] > WHEN[value='" + productName + "'] ALLOWEDVALUES > LISTITEM[value='" + listItem + "']");
 $listItem.val(newListItemValue);
```

It does not update the listitem value

Also tried .prop("value") and .attr("value") on $listItem.

Would be very thankful for a working jsfiddle with the above xml sample, which edits the value attribute of LISTITEM

Comment: Changing the value of an XML doc in memory seems a little pointless. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to change the LISTITEM elements' "value" attribute values in the xml

Comment: Well, yes, but why? What do you do with the XML after you change the value?

Comment: I upload it back to the server from where I downloaded it originally (and created a treeview object on a webpage - with some Add/Edit/Delete context menus for easier manipulation, don't have XML-affine users)

Comment: Do you have any backend? Probably will be better to delegate the task of downloading and uploading the xml there, and later render the form, containing this data in  the frontend. I dont know your infrastructure, but it's a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `$(xml)` you are creating a new DOM object based on the original string. Try this instead:

```
j = $(xml);
j.find('attr').attr('foo', 'bar');
console.log(j.html());
```

Now you parse the XML string only once and update the resulting node.